# Add filter with Powershell compare_object

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have two .csv files and I need to compare them.
The first one is an extract of the Active Directory, the other is an extract of the registry Profile list.

When I compare them, I want to only display users who are present in the Profile list, disabled in the Active Directory and add a filter to only show those within the domain ("DOMAIN\Username").

```
compare-object -referenceobject $(get-content C:\Temp\UsersAD.csv) -differenceobject $(get-content C:\Temp\ProfileList.csv) | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
```

Here's what I got with this script :

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN> C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN\Downloads\compare_users.ps1

InputObject                                                    SideIndicator                                                
-----------                                                    -------------                                                
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject     =>                                                           
"PSChildName"                                                  =>                                                           
"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"                                          =>                                                           
"NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE"                                   =>                                                           
"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"                                 =>                                                           
"LocalName\Administrator"                                      =>                                                           
"NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID"                              =>                                                           
"IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5"                                        =>                                                           
"IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic"                                =>
```

Ideally it should look like this :

```
PSChildName
"DOMAIN\Username1"
"DOMAIN\Username2"
```

I tried to add a filter at the end but with no result as it's not a valid command:

```
compare-object -referenceobject $(get-content C:\Temp\UsersAD.csv) -differenceobject $(get-content C:\Temp\ProfileList.csv) -Filter "DOMAIN\" | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
```

Here's what the registry Profile list looks like originally :

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
PSChildName
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LoacalName\Administrator
DOMAIN\Username
DOMAIN\Administrator
NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID
IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5
IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic
```

So actually I need the opposite of what I get with the Compare-Object command (i.e "DOMAIN\Username" and "DOMAIN\Administrator").

The code for enabled Active Directory users :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' | 
Select-Object SamAccountName,@{Name='FullUserName';Expression={"DOMAIN\$($_.SamAccountName)"}} |
Export-CSV C:\Temp\UsersEnabled.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

The result :

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
FullUserName
DOMAIN\Administrator
DOMAIN\User1
DOMAIN\User2
```

Comment: Please update your question to describe in what way the command doesn't work, using sample input and expected output, ideally in the form of an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "_, disabled in the Active Directory..._" I don't see anything in your data or code that would indicate whether a User/Profile is enabled or disabled. Could you clarify ? Could you also include a mock up (excerpt) of the CSV file from the Active Directory ?

Comment: @PetruZaharia I have two .csv files. One that shows me enabled users in the active directory and another that shows me the local profile list. So if I compare them, it will show me if a user has a local profile but is disabled in the active directory (I added the code for the enabled users in the post).

Answer (score 0):

The `Compare-Object` cmdlet has a `-Property` parameter where you can specify a specific property to compare between the two object collections.

You also should use `Import-CSV` to read the CSVs, rather than `Get-Content`. This will turn the CSVs back in to PowerShell objects.

At the moment your two collections likely have entirely different property sets and you're trying to compare them in their entirety. You need to ensure that the way you get the data output ensures both CSVs have a single property with the same name where the data in that field is in the same format.

For example (not necessarily correct, depending on your data, this assumes both CSVs would have a "name" property where the user names were in the same format):

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Import-CSV C:\Temp\UsersAD.csv) `
               -DifferenceObject (Import-CSV C:\Temp\ProfileList.csv) `
               -Property name | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
```

Comment: I modified a property, so now both have a "FullUserName" property with the fields in the same format, but your code doesn't display what I'm looking for. It gave me the exact same thing I had with my code. I need to apply a filter to this code which will only give me results starting with "DOMAIN\"